# Oracle select same id where 2 exist

Tags: sql, oracle

so this query of this Oracle table shows 2 rows with same id

```
SELECT INDIVIDUAL_ID,DATE1,DATE2
FROM RESIDENCE_PERIOD
WHERE INDIVIDUAL_ID = 401865003800;
```

all good --

```
401865003800    20-05-02    20-05-20
401865003800    20-06-01    20-06-30
```

but there are other ids that have more than 1 entry as well so this query:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM RESIDENCE_PERIOD rp 
  WHERE  rp.INDIVIDUAL_ID IN
                    (SELECT rp2.INDIVIDUAL_ID
                     FROM RESIDENCE_PERIOD rp2
                    GROUP BY rp2.INDIVIDUAL_ID
                    HAVING COUNT(rp2.INDIVIDUAL_ID) > 1)
    AND ROWNUM <=2
  ORDER BY rp.INDIVIDUAL_ID;
```

works but brings back 2 different ids that both have more than 1 entry

```
276460366513
401865003800
```

I don't care which id I get. I just want both of the ids to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use an analytical function like this to fetch the entire row for all the same ids having more than one record:

```
  Select p.* from
     (Select p.*,
             Count(1) over (partition by P.INDIVIDUAL_ID ) as cnt
        From RESIDENCE_PERIOD p) p
       Where cnt>1
 Order by INDIVIDUAL_ID
```